# Spring-xd sink:file rollover support

Tags: spring-xd

I found [request for sink:file rollover support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-297), but it seems idle for more than a year now. What's the chance of adding this to spring-xd? In the mean time, is there a way to accomplish this without installing/deploying HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom file sink; also make a comment and/or vote for that JIRA issue.